# Как выгрузить базу 1С в Postgresql

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, 1с, мобильная-разработка

Как лучше выгрузить базу 1С в postgresql или sqllite, чтобы в дальнейшем использовать ее в своем мобильном приложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как структура БД 1С - это весьма мрачная реализация [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) с автогенерируемыми таблицами и колонками, лучше через посредника. Или подключить базу PostgreSQL как внешний источник данных и написать обработку для переноса данных из справочников и регистров в этот источник, либо написать обработку для выгрузки нужных данных в файлы формата [CSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV), а потом загрузить полученные файлы с помощью [psql](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/app-psql) например.